Cómo puedo leer string[] args sin IndexOutOfRangeException cuando no haya nada puesto? (C#)
Es que en mi aplicación, se puede pasar un archivo con argumentos, pero no siempre hay, entonces, cuando no hay, me sale System.IndexOutOfRangeException, aquí va el código:
if (args != null)
{
    string file = args[0]; // <- Línea que causa la excepción
    RecipeOpened.RecipeRute = file;
    RecipeOpened.OpenedByFile = true;
    Application.Run(new RecipeOpened());
}
else
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

Y se supone que si no hay nada en args, debería ser null, pero no, porque aun así se ejecuta la línea que no se debería ejecutar cuando es null

No confundir un array vacío (con cero elementos) con un array nulo, son cosas distintas
En la documentación dice:

La matriz args no puede ser NULL. así que es seguro acceder a la
propiedad Length sin comprobar los valores NULL.

Y es lo mismo que te dice el código
static void Main(string[] args) //Así es normalmente
//----------------------------------------

//                       ↓ el '?' lo convierte en nulleabe
static void Main(string[]? args) //Así sería se pudiera ser null


Entonces tu código debería ser
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    string file = args[0]; // <- Línea que causa la excepción
    RecipeOpened.RecipeRute = file;
    RecipeOpened.OpenedByFile = true;
    Application.Run(new RecipeOpened());
}
else
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}


Muchas gracias, me ha solucionado el error
